# How to edit Woocommerce product page in my own themplate

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, styles

I have build my own Wordpress theme and activated Woocommerce. Almost everypage works fine. But my Store and Product pages are not in Container. Also I would like to chanche the positions of sertain items on the Product Page. Theme is build in Bootstrap so I would like to use Bootstrapp to fix my Product page. The biggest problem is that I cannot find the right file to edit... Somebody got the solution?

You can check the site [here](http://www.homanict.nl/allekleurenvanderegenboog).

Thanks!!

Comment: Please read the documentation on [third party theme compatibility](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/)

Answer (score 0):

To build a WooCommerce Compatible theme, you need to edit the WooCommerce templates.

All the WooCommerce templates are located at woocommerce/templates folder. If you are not familiar with WooCommerce templates structure, you can install [WooCommerce Template Hints](https://tw.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-template-hints/), and it will display the template file name to show you where the content comes from.

To customize the template, please follow the [best practices](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) so your modifications will not be missing when you update WooCommerce.

Comment: You are welcome. If it is helpful, please accept the answer, thank you!